# Divide the rows equally into 3 columns

Tags: html, css, html-table, angular-material2

I am using a mattable, let say i have 26 records then i need to show the first 10 records in Column1, next 10 in column 2 and next 6 in column 3. Is their any way i can acheive this with CSS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a solution using CSS GRID. Posting the link below :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mzpbos

Answer (score 0):

use `display flex`

html

```
<div class="main-row">
   <div class="col">
   </div>
    <div class="col">
   </div>
    <div class="col">
   </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.main-row{
  display:flex;
}

.col{
  flex-grow:1;
  height:150px;
  background-color:#e5e5e5;
  margin:0px 2px;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this would work , since i need the records to be arranged vertically rather than the normal flow.